# How do I access the top level component from within the Script tag?

Tags: apache-flex

I have done this many times but can't remember the syntax for the life of me and am obviously asking Google the wrong questions.

If I have an MXML file like this (MyExample.mxml):

```
<s:TitleWindow
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

        ]]>
    </fx:Script> 
</s:TitleWindow>
```

I can't give the TitleWindow an id as it's the top level component. How do I access the TitleWindow component from inside the script tag, the 'this' keyword will give me type Object, which one of its properties will give me the title window?

Cheers,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `this` keyword to refer to the top level component in your MXML Component file.

```
<s:TitleWindow
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
         public function doStuff():void{
           trace(this);
           trace(this.width);
           trace(this.height);
           trace(this.otherProperty);
         }
    ]]>
</fx:Script> 
</s:TitleWindow>
```

If you want to access the actual Title Skin part, you can do so by accessing the [titleDisplay](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TitleWindow.html#top) skin part, most likely in a partAdded method.